# How do I make my code redirect to another page with a specific login?

Tags: php, html, authentication, redirect, admin

I'm having problems trying to set a specific login to redirect to the admin page, I didn't want to add more columns in the database because time is running out and I wanted to know how to make it work.

My code is practically functional, except for the part where only that login redirects to the page... All the wrong logins I try end up redirecting there, and I wish only that one did and the others ended up giving an error.

This is my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klzlj.png).

Comment: Please add your code here to your question as text and not simply as a picture

Comment: Incidentally your code is wide open to SQL injection - use `prepared statements` instead of directly inserting user supplied content.